# How can I create a screen like my example?

Tags: android, screenshot

[image] .

I want to create a screen for Android similar to the above example.
How can I leave the blank at the edges? And how do I make the sign of ">" at the end of all sentences?

Comment: Use Custom Listview for that.

Answer (score 2):

Use "Custom Listview" for that and see below 2 link for custom listview example, it may help you.

[Arrow Image to the Right of a ListView](http://willvk.blogspot.in/2011/07/adding-arrow-image-to-right-of-listview.html)

[Building a Custom Fancy ListView in Android](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/building-a-custom-fancy-listview-in-android/)

[Android Custom ListView with Image and Text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create `Custom List view` for this and set the adapter for the listview which will `inflate the layout` having two image views and textview.`'>'` you are asking about is the imageview kept at the right side(gravity) of the layout and nothing else.

To understand clearly see this [Custom Listview](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) link which help you to create this.

Comment: greatest answer thank you for best answering :) .Blanks ( gaps ) at all edges??

Comment: if you are satisfied with my answer than you should accept it which would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

The "blank" you are talking about is padding. You are going to have to use a ListView and create an adapter of controls

You then create a control for each element in the list: with two images and a textview. You would probably use a RelativeLayout. You add the icon imageview first (padding it on the left and right) to make the "blanks". Then you add the TextView, and then you add the last ImageView which contains the picture of the ">" and align it to the right. (The first two components will be left aligned).

Then you just create an adapter with the desired items you want, changing the icon image and TextView text for each element.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html